# Getting the pk from url in Django

Tags: python, html, django

here is my URL structure that I use to get the item pk in the link :

**urls.py**

```
path('categories/<int:item_category>/', views.item_category, name="item_category"),
```

**views.py**

```
def item_category(request, pk):
    item_category = get_object_or_404(Categories, pk=pk)
    ids = [self.kwargs.get('pk')]
    cat_id = Categories.objects.get(pk=ids)

    return render(request, 'items_modal.html', {'item_category': item_category,
                                                'cat_id': cat_id
                                                })
```

Now I want to use the pk to get the result on the new link 
here is my **HTML**

```
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ cat_id }}</h5>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a couple of errors.

1. change the url:

   `path('categories/<int:pk>/', views.item_category, name="item_category"),`
2. Your function is confusing. You do not want a variable with the same name as a function which is getting you object and cat_id is an object and not an integer

   `def item_category(request, pk):
       cat = get_object_or_404(Categories, pk=
       return render(request, 'items_modal.html', {'item_category': cat})`
3. Displaying the id:

   `<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">< ahref="{% url 'item_category' item_category.id %}">{{ item_category }}</a></h5>`

Comment: gave me no noReverse error `Reverse for 'item_category' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['categories\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
`

Comment: Amended part 3. I was thinking I had called it `cat` but I had left it as `item_category`

Comment: @HenryM thank you. You just saved me at least half hour of searching and digging.

Answer (score 0):

change the keyword in url

```
path('categories/<int:pk>/', views.item_category, name="item_category"),
```